# Pass scope to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey is it possible to pass scope to our ng-repeat loop as property?
For example

```js
<li ng-repeat="e in data">{{e.someScope}}</li>
```

```html
scope.someScope = "property";
```

I tryed do this like this, but its not working.

```js
<li ng-repeat="e in data">{{e}}{{+.+}}{{someScope}}</li>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexer notation instead and use ng-bind to avoid the interpolation altogether, since someScope is a property of the scope object, not of e.  In addition, trying to interpolate `.` in combination with property lookup on an object will result in a parsing error:

```
<li ng-repeat="e in data"><span ng-bind="e[someScope]"></span></li>
```

Comment: Beste, Thanks! :) BTW. React is simple for more advantage UI :P

Comment: Happy to help!  Please remember to mark it as selected answer so that others will find it useful as well.